# how to embed html code in template in polymer3 (like unsafeHTML)

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-elements, lit-element, lit-html

[please check the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UdZwlHrzmsLB8LY8f4dx)

```
static get template() {
   return html`
     <p>This content is from ChildClass.</p>
     <p>${super.template}</p>
     <p>Hello again from ChildClass.</p>
     <p style='color:red'>[[partHtml]] <==== this should be 'hello'</p>
     `;  
 }
 get partHtml()
 {
   return "<span>hello</span>";
 }
```

I want `partHtml` to be injected into a template like normal HTML.

I know unsafe HTML in lit-element can do that, but lit-element just can't use `super.render()` things, it is not convenient like polymer-element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer when I debug into the call stack.
just use `htmlLiteral`, key code likes this

```
import {PolymerElement, html} from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/polymer@3.0.5/polymer-element.js'
import {htmlLiteral} from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/polymer@3.0.5/lib/utils/html-tag.js'

....

  static get template() {
      return html`<p style='color:red'>${this.partHtml} <==== this should be 'hello'</p>`;  
  }
  static get partHtml()
  {
    return htmlLiteral `<span>hello</span>` ;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using `inner-h-t-m-l` attribute

```
static get template() {
   return html`
     <p>This content is from ChildClass.</p>
     <p>${super.template}</p>
     <p>Hello again from ChildClass.</p>
     <p style='color:red' inner-h-t-m-l="[[partHtml]]"></p>
     `;  
 }
 get partHtml()
 {
   return "<span>hello</span>";
 }
```

Comment: it looks so hacky code...

another way,how do i use inner-h-t-m-l in code like this?

`static get template() {
        return html `[[iconStr]]`;
    }
     get iconStr()
    {
       return "<span>123</span>";
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiline String

```
static get template() {
  return html`
   <p>This content is from ChildClass.</p>
   <p>${super.template}</p>
   <p>Hello again from ChildClass.</p>
   <p style='color:red'>${this.partHtml}</p>
 `;  
}
static get partHtml() {
  return html`<span>hello</span>`;
}
```

[Test on Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/R47OEzejKwe3JjDzN87x?p=preview)